# Printer printing error on page

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I created an application which generates a pdf file with PDFSharp

Its al going great. but the moment the document is printed on paper the following message is printed on a second page(The generated pdf is always a one page document)

ERROR: undefined 
OFFENDING COMMAND: CUE

STACK:

The stack is empty
But i cant find any information related to this error.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add more information about your error. Steps for reproduce and some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems like to problem was that the content was larger then the page itself
But it didnt get an extra page so i changed some margins and i do not get the error anymore.

sorry for the inconvience